# Angular Material form field Long label overlapping with input text

Tags: angular, angular-material

Angular material form field label overlaps with entered text, Also multiple cosmetic issues?
Long labels with fields have issue with responsiveness. Check stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ar2ulq

Any Solution?
Condition : Complete label should be visible, it should not get shrink.

Comment: WHAT YOU WANT? if text of label is big then textbox width should be increase?

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the label white-space property:

```
  <mat-form-field class="field-label-ellipsis" appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
    <mat-label>
      Legacy form field long Long long Long long Long long Long long Long lon
      Long long Long long Long long Long label
    </mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder" />
    <mat-hint>Hint</mat-hint>
  </mat-form-field>
```

And the CSS:

```
.field-label-ellipsis mat-label {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[Working example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ar2ulq-1v88ei?file=src/app/form-field-appearance-example.html)

Comment: Label should be visible for better user experience

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
 textarea {
   padding-top: 20px;
}
```